# How do I disable FPS Meter on Google Chrome Canary?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-canary

I'm unable to disable the FPS window which appears in the upper-right of any window in Chrome Canary 38.0.2113.0, Win.

It appears in my rendered window, the dev tools window and any other open page such as an iframe.

I've disabled it under "Rendering" in Dev tools, but it won't go away. Is there a way to hide it, or is it just part of Canary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. In the address bar, go to: **about:flags** (or  **chrome://flags/#show-fps-counter**)
2. Click "Disable" beneath **FPS counter**
3. Restart browser

Comment: have you found out how to disable only the one in devtools?

Comment: Yes, open Dev Tools and press "Esc"

This will open the drawer at the bottom of Dev Tools.

Click on the **Rendering** Tab and deselect "Show FPS meter"